# Colored Shadow by Color Thief

Tags: javascript, css, color-thief

I'm trying to make a shadow of an image using Color Thief (like the image below):

[image: Colored shadow]

I'm trying to make Color Thief detect the color and make the shadow look like the shadow colored by the color that came from Color Thief.

How can I do this?

Comment: Well.. yes, you probably could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to cross-domain issues with canvas and images, I can't produce a working snippet here, but this should do the trick (maybe with some slight tweaks).

```js
var $img = $('img');

$img.load(function() {
  var colorThief = new ColorThief();
  // uncomment this (x-domain issues):
  //var color = colorThief.getColor($img.get(0));

  // here's what it would produce:
  var color = 'rgb(72, 174, 216)';

  $img.css('box-shadow', color + ' 0 5px 15px');
});
```

```css
img {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px auto 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

canvas {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/color-thief/2.0.1/color-thief.min.js"></script>

<img id="image" src="https://i.imgur.com/rb3admc.jpg" />
```

Comment: How can I apply to a specific class of image ??

Comment: @YoussefElmajbri Change the first line to `var $img = $('.your_class');`. Since I answered your question, please feel free to mark my answer as correct with the checkmark to close this question.

Answer (score -2):

You can add multiple shadows in different colors with this generator
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Box-shadow_generator.

Comment: Not what OP is asking: `I'm trying to make Color Thief detect the color and make the shadow look like the shadow colored by the color that came from Color Thief`